# Difference between BuildUp and Resolve

Tags: c#, unity-container, dependency-resolver

I am playing around with Unity Library, as at my workplace it is highly used, so wanted to understand its different behaviours.

I am confused about `BuildUp` and `Resolve` because they seem to do same thing so i am not getting when it is suitable to use `BuildUp` and when `Resolve`.

Am i missing something ?

Here is example :

```
public class Decorations
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public string Footer { get; set; }
}

public class Printer
{
    internal void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HEADER: {0}", this.Decorations != null
            && this.Decorations.Header != null
                ? this.Decorations.Header
                : string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.WriteLine("FOOTER: {0}", this.Decorations != null
            && this.Decorations.Footer != null
                ? this.Decorations.Footer
                : string.Empty);
    }

    [Dependency]
    public Decorations Decorations { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public void Print(Printer printer, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.BuildUp(printer);
        printer.Print("Hello from ClassA");
        container.Teardown(printer);
    }
}
```

Example using `Resolve<T>()` :

```
        var printer = new Printer();

        var containerA = new UnityContainer();
        containerA.RegisterInstance(new Decorations
        {
            Header = "I am HEADER from Decorations #1",
            Footer = "I am FOOTER from Decorations #1"
        });

        var a = new ClassA();

        var objClassA = containerA.Resolve<Decorations>();
```

and here is example using `BuildUp()`:

```
        var printer = new Printer();

        var containerA = new UnityContainer();
        containerA.RegisterInstance(new Decorations
        {
            Header = "I am HEADER from Decorations #1",
            Footer = "I am FOOTER from Decorations #1"
        });


        var a = new ClassA();

        var objClassA = containerA.Resolve<Decorations>();

        a.Print(printer, containerA);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Resolve` is used to *instantiate an instance of an object*, and inject dependencies.

`BuildUp` is used to inject dependencies into an *existing instance* of an object.

Comment: what i am understanding is `BuildUp()` is for property injection  in already instantiated object. Am i right ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - not just property injection, I think it will also do method too.

Comment: what you mean by method injection ? can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You can mark a method to be called on dependency injection, if this takes further dependencies, these will be resolved by the container. More info in the documentation no doubt.

Comment: can i delete my question as it is already answered here